# %Like% Query in spring JpaRepository

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I would like to write a like query in `JpaRepository` but it is not returning anything :

`LIKE '%place%'`-its not working.

`LIKE 'place'` works perfectly.

Here is my code :

```
@Repository("registerUserRepository")
public interface RegisterUserRepository extendsJpaRepository<Registration,Long> {

    @Query("Select c from Registration c where c.place like :place")
     List<Registration> findByPlaceContaining(@Param("place")String place);
}
```

Answer (score 263, accepted):

The spring data JPA query needs the "%" chars as well as a space char following `like` in your query, as in

`@Query("Select c from Registration c where c.place like %:place%")`.

Cf. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html.

You may want to get rid of the `@Query`annotation alltogether, as it seems to resemble the standard query (automatically implemented by the spring data proxies); i.e. using the single line

```
List<Registration> findByPlaceContaining(String place);
```

is sufficient.

Comment: It may be useful also to ignore case for a query, using: findByPlaceIgnoreCaseContaining(String place);

Comment: Just as a side comment - you can't mix and match %:param% with %param% inside the same query. Otherwise the app will not even start.

Comment: Thank you. I used to write `like '%:place%'` with `'` and there were no results at all, because Hibernate adds `'`s to strings by itself.

Comment: This is not a good response and it is potentially dangerous as well. Spring has this sorted out with ContainingIgnoreCase, check my answer bellow.

Comment: @Query("Select c from Registration c where c.place like %:place%").

is not working in Spring Boot Version 2.3.3. 

would you please give some idea about why can I make it work while using 2.3.3

Comment: @SubhaBhowmik Which version is exactly not working? You say for 2.3.3 it's working and not working. I was also struggling with %:param% with Spring Boot 2.4.0 but figured out that you cannot have %:param% inside an SQL function: F.e. in LOWER('%:param%') the :param is not substituted because of the quote signs. Hope that can help you.

Comment: like with ignore case
`@Query("Select c from Registration c where lower(c.place) like lower(concat('%', :place,'%')")`

Comment: This doesn't work with reactive driver (R2DBC). Got ```io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory$PostgresqlBadGrammarException: [42601] syntax error at or near "%"```

Answer (score 129):

You dont actually need the `@Query` annotation at all.

You can just use the following

```
    @Repository("registerUserRepository")
    public interface RegisterUserRepository extends JpaRepository<Registration,Long>{
    
    List<Registration> findByPlaceIgnoreCaseContaining(String place);

    }
```

Comment: For me this one is the best solution. i didn't know you can use IgnoreCase combined with Containing, It isn't in the documentation.

Comment: What about the case when I want to use many columns ? - I believe `@Query()` is a must, right ? With that approach I would have to make `or` that isn't actually a well suited solution for that case:`findByField1OrField2Containg(String phraseForField1, String phraseForField2)`

Answer (score 43):

For your case, you can directly use JPA methods. That code is like bellow :

**Containing: select ... like %:place%**

```
List<Registration> findByPlaceContainingIgnoreCase(String place);
```

here, **IgnoreCase** will help you to search item with ignoring the case.

**Using @Query in JPQL** :

```
@Query("Select registration from Registration registration where 
registration.place LIKE  %?1%")
List<Registration> findByPlaceContainingIgnoreCase(String place);
```

Here are some related methods:

> 1. **Like** `findByPlaceLike`
>
>    … where x.place like ?1
> 2. **StartingWith** `findByPlaceStartingWith`
>
>    … where x.place like ?1 (parameter bound with appended %)
> 3. **EndingWith** `findByPlaceEndingWith`
>
>    … where x.place like ?1 (parameter bound with prepended %)
> 4. **Containing** `findByPlaceContaining`
>
>    … where x.place like ?1 (parameter bound wrapped in %)

More info, view [this link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) (where the above quote is from), [this link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/repository-query-keywords.html) and [this](https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpql/)

Answer (score 33):

You can also implement the like queries using Spring Data JPA supported keyword ["Containing"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation).

```
List<Registration> findByPlaceContaining(String place);
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this.

```
@Query("Select c from Registration c where c.place like '%'||:place||'%'")
```

Comment: Helpful if we use `something=:place` and `another like %:place%` in query.

Answer (score 7):

You can have one alternative of using placeholders as:

```
@Query("Select c from Registration c where c.place LIKE  %?1%")
List<Registration> findPlaceContainingKeywordAnywhere(String place);
```

Answer (score 6):

I use this:

```
@Query("Select c from Registration c where lower(c.place) like lower(concat('%', concat(:place, '%')))")
```

lower() is like toLowerCase in String, so the result isn't case sensitive.

Comment: I use the same method but when variable in lower function is null I get the following error, how to add a null check?
function lower(bytea) does not exist

Answer (score 3):

when call funtion, I use:
`findByPlaceContaining("%" + place);`

or:
`findByPlaceContaining(place + "%");`

or:
`findByPlaceContaining("%" + place + "%");`

Answer (score 2):

We can use native query

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value ="Select * from Registration as c where c.place like %:place%")

List<Registration> findByPlaceContaining(@Param("place")String place);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to use something like this `CONCAT('%',:setName,'%')`

Answer (score 1):

answer exactly will be

```
-->` @Query("select u from Category u where u.categoryName like %:input%")
     List findAllByInput(@Param("input") String input);
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be various approaches. As mentioned in answer of many, if possible you can use JPA predefined template query.

```
List<Registration> findByPlaceContainingIgnoreCase(String place);
```

Also, you can append '%' in java layer before calling the above method.

If complex query, then you can normally use @Query one

```
@Query("Select r from Registration r where r.place like '%' || :place || '%'")
```

For readability, you can use below one

```
@Query("Select r from Registration r where r.place like CONCAT('%', :place, '%'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution without `@Query` (actually I tried which one which is "accepted". However, it didn't work).

Have to return `Page<Entity>` instead of `List<Entity>`:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository 
                          extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Integer> {
    Page<Employee> findAllByNameIgnoreCaseStartsWith(String name, Pageable pageable);
}
```

`IgnoreCase` part was critical for achieving this!

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply say 'Like' keyword after parameters..

```
List<Employee> findAllByNameLike(String name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Us like this

@Query("from CasFhgDeviceView where deviceGroupName  like concat(concat('%CSGW%', :usid), '%') ")

Comment: Does this answer provide more information than the other answers?  If so, please [edit] it and add information about what your answer helps solve.  If not, please delete your answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with ***Spring Data JPA***. Check out http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example

```
Registration registration = new Registration();
registration.setPlace("UK");

ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matchingAll()
  .withIgnoreCase()
  .withStringMatcher(StringMatcher.CONTAINING);

Example<Registration> example = Example.of(registration, matcher);

List<Registration> registrationList = registerUserRepository.findAll(example);
```