# Spring Data JPA - How can I fetch data from a Date column using only month and day?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple Spring Data JPA project working with mysql and I need to fetch all registers that match the day and month. The column I need to filter is type Datetime.

```
1935-12-08 00:00:00
```

If I want to do this in a db level it works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM my_database.event where event_date LIKE '%-12-08%';
```

It treats the date as a string. Now I need to do this in my repository yet nothing seems to work. I tried the basic one:

```
List<Event> findByEventDateLike(
        @Param("eventDate") Date eventDate);
```

but it says it returns an illegal argument exception since it is a Date object. I tried other combinations but apparently spring data jpa can't compare dates with partial information.

**NOTE:** To keep it clean I'm trying to avoid @Query sentences but if it is the only way to go, it is a valid answer.

How can I do it?

Comment: If you want to use like '%%' you have to chage the type to String

Comment: How about change method name to `findByEventDateGreaterThanAndEventDateLessThan(Date startDate, Date endDate)`

Comment: you can find more details here  https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

Comment: Yes the problem with that in particular is that I need it to return something like "On this day in history" so It should return everything that happened on this day through the years.

Comment: @Osgux is there a way to do it without modifying my eventDate property in my Entity? I'm using it as it is in other calls.

Comment: could be create a native query and parse date to string like 2017-12-08

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use nativeQuery to emulate the query in the Database.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_date Like %?1%", nativeQuery = true)
List<Match> findByMatchMonthAndMatchDay(@Param ("eventDate") String eventDate);
```

The DB takes care of the conversion between Date/String for the LIKE clause.

Passing the param as "-month-day" (e.g.: -12-08) will return a collection of events with that string in the date field.

Answer (score 16):

If your JPA provider is Hibernate then you can use `year` and `month` (and [other funcs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-functions)) in your JPQL (HQL) query, for example like this:

```
@Query("select e from Event e where year(e.eventDate) = ?1 and month(e.eventDate) = ?2")
List<Entity> getByYearAndMonth(int year, int month);
```

Comment: and also  day(e.eventDate)=?3 and hour(e.eventDate)=?4 works too. Perfect!

Comment: and if it's not Hibernate?

Answer (score 3):

The code below works for ZonedDateTime (startDate), don't have an opportunity to test against DateTime right now:

```
@Query("SELECT b FROM Box b " +
        "WHERE EXTRACT (day FROM b.startDate) = :dayOfMonth AND EXTRACT (month FROM b.startDate) = :month")
List<Box> findBoxWithParticularDayAndMonth(@Param("dayOfMonth") Integer dayOfMonth, @Param("month") Integer month);
```

Usage:

```
List<Box> boxes = boxRepo.findBoxWithParticularDayAndMonth(22, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Java: Date to String
[Convert java.util.Date to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683728/convert-java-util-date-to-string)

```
@Query("select e from Event e where e.eventDate like %:eventDate%")
List<Entity> findByEventDateLike(@Param("eventDate")String eventDate);
```

for me the easy way is parse Date to String but I found another solution you could be try

[%Like% Query in spring JpaRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362540/like-query-in-spring-jparepository)
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Containing

findByFirstnameContaining

… where x.firstname like ?1 (parameter bound wrapped in %)

Comment: It does not work, jpa throws an exception it does not consider the eventDate as string, it still assume it as date.