# Native Query Like Format Issue in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

I am trying to use like operator in native query as below:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT max(id) FROM EMP where id like ___:country%", nativeQuery=true)
```

country as input parameter for method.

getting the below error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter name : country

can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [%Like% Query in spring JpaRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362540/like-query-in-spring-jparepository)

Comment: Hello @Mehraj Malik, It's not duplicate to that as i have seen that and implemented the query like as same but the format is different. If i used like this %:country% then its working but not working for ___:country% format.

Answer (score 0):

use JPA query in your repository interface like this:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT max(r_id) FROM registrations WHERE r_name LIKE ?1")
int getCount (String name);
```

when you call this function add modulus(%) with your string like this:

```
@Autowired
private RegistrationRepository registrationRepository;        

    @GetMapping(value = "/reg-like")
    @ResponseBody
    public void regLike() {
        int max = registrationRepository.getCount("s%");
        System.out.println("" + max);
    }
```

Or you can try something like this:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT max(r_id) FROM registrations WHERE r_name LIKE %?1")
int getCount (String name);
```

Then you can omit the modulus(%), when calling the function.

See official documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods).

Comment: you can mark my answer as solution, as it solves your issue.