# spring data jdbc - @query with like

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

In Spring Data JDBC,  How I can write in CrudRepository a query with "like", I have try with this one, but it throws an error

@Query("select * from people p where name like :startOfName%")

org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select * from people p where name like ?%]; SQL state [S0001]; error code [102]; Incorrect syntax near '%'.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '%'.

I have seen this query in this topic for JpaRepository, but it is not working with spring data jdbc:
[%Like% Query in spring JpaRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362540/like-query-in-spring-jparepository)
@Query("Select c from Registration c where c.place like %:place%").

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: I know that the value of the parameter can have %, but is there any way to enforce the last %?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data JDBC doesn't yet support this short syntax. You'll have to write full SQL statement:

```
select * from people p where name like concat(:startOfName,'%')
```